# sorting list by select element item using angular js

Tags: angularjs

here is my code i want to sort items in list by selecting from drop down but it displays even nothing please give me a answer how can i get value of items and then sort data

    
        
        var app = angular.module("app", []);
            app.controller(ShoppingCartCtrl,function($scope)  {

```
        $scope.items = [
        {Name: "Soap", Price: "25", Quantity: "10"},
        {Name: "Shaving cream", Price: "50", Quantity: "15"},
        {Name: "Shampoo", Price: "100", Quantity: "5"}
              ];

        $scope.mySortFunction = function(item) {
        if(isNaN(item[$scope.sortExpression]))
        return item[$scope.sortExpression];
        return parseInt(item[$scope.sortExpression]);
        }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="app">
        <span class="bold">Demonstrating filtering and sorting using Angular     JS</span>
        <br /><br />
        <div ng-controller="ShoppingCartCtrl">
            <div>
                Sort by: 
                <select ng-model="sortExpression">
                    <option value="Name">Name</option>
                    <option value="Price">Price</option>
                    <option value="Quantity">Quantity</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <br />
            <div><strong>Filter Results</strong></div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Any: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.$" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Name: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Price: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Price" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>By Quantity: </td>
                    <td><input type="text" ng-model="search.Quantity" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <table border="1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:mySortFunction | filter:search">
                        <td>{{item.Name}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Price | currency}}</td>
                        <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <br />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code in plunkr ??

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vkums8t5/ i want now get data from url and then sorted by selecting an element can you help me Anik Islam

Answer (score 0):

if do not use filter or orderby, it can be done like:

```
//watch sortBy
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.sortExpression
}, function(newSort) {
    $scope.items.sort(sortBy(newSort))
})

//sortBy
function sortBy(sortExp) {
    return function(a, b) {
        return a[sortExp] > b[sortExp] ? 1 : -1
    }
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vkums8t5/ i want now get data from url and then sorted by selecting an element can you help me @ZHAO Xudong

Comment: if i sort i sort only one type like ascending or descending its working but i need both of them now i add 2 more options in drop down that looks like title ASC,Title DESC,Score ASC,Score DESC now kindly guide me how can i do this what changes i do to achieve that ?

Answer (score 0):

This works: http://jsfiddle.net/F9JDS/14/

```
app.controller('ShoppingCartCtrl', function ($scope) {
  ...
}
```

Make sure ShoppingCartCtrl is a string when you pass it to app.controller.

Comment: That's weird because it's working in the jsfiddle. If you open the developer console, are there any errors? That will give some hints as to the difference between our environments.